# Are there open source implementations of Wavefront OBJ loaders for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, wavefront

I would like to display 3-D models of building interiors in my iPhone application, but they are in Wavefront OBJ format.  Is there an open source implementation of a Wavefront OBJ loader that I could use within my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both [Bill Dudney](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/wave_front_obj_textures_working) and [Jeff LaMarche](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/wavefront-obj-loader-open-sourced-to.html) have implementations of Wavefront OBJ loaders for the iPhone that you should be able to drop into your project.  Note, however, that Jeff LaMarche's implementation [no longer works on iOS5](http://code.google.com/p/iphonewavefrontloader/issues/detail?id=22), [is no longer actively developed, and was never intended as production code](https://twitter.com/#!/jeff_lamarche/status/142686916482043904).

Additionally, since I originally wrote this, Jonathan Wight has released his [TouchOpenGL](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchOpenGL) code, which includes an OBJ loader.

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I tried Jeff LaMarche's implementation, but my model looked awful; triangles in mesh appearing and disappearing. I guess I need to dust off my Foley and Van Damm text......

Answer (score 3):

Note: I'm the author of this framework.

Rend, my Objective-C based OpenGL ES 2.0 framework contains an Wavefront OBJ loader. The class is called REWavefrontMesh.

http://github.com/antonholmquist/rend-ios/blob/master/Classes/REWavefrontMesh.h
http://github.com/antonholmquist/rend-ios/blob/master/Classes/REWavefrontMesh.m